# How to pass a value of a variable from view to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

using form post method i need to pass a value of `numID`to a controller

for example assigning a value to `numID` inside view,

```
$numID= 25;
```

i need to use value of `numID` in a controller and assign that to `temp` variable. so i use following line of code,

```
$temp= $_POST[numID];
```

but its unable to get the exact value. Please help me on this. If have any other alternate way please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of sending info from view to the controller:

View:

```
<?php echo form_open('invoice'); ?>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_input('order_num', $this->input->post('order_num')); ?>
<?php echo form_submit('submit','submit'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Controller:

```
public function invoice()
{
$order = $this->input->post('order_num');
$this->General_Model->get_customer_order($order);
}
```

Model:

```
function get_customer_order($order)
{
 . . .
$this->db->where('client_orders.id', $order);
$result = $this->db->get('client_orders');
. . .
}
```

Note we are using the input name and id as `= "order_num"`
Then we ask the controller to find it as `$this->input->post('order_num');`