# Pass php variable from view to controller to model using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to pass php variable from view to controller then in my model using codeigniter.

The problem is that the variable is not getting passed to the controller.

Below is my View and Controller code.

Please note that the variable is got onload not through form inputs.

**This is my View**

```js
<script>
                                        
 $(document).ready(function (){
    //fill data
         fillgrid();
    
    function fillgrid(){
        $("#loader").show();
        $.ajax({
            var subcategory_id = <?php echo $sub_id; ?>,
            url:'<?php echo base_url() ?>Shop/get_products_in_sub_subcategory/'+subcategory_id,
            type:'GET'
        }).done(function (data){
            $("#fillgrid").html(data);
            $("#loader").hide();
            
        });
    }
    
});
</script>
```

**Controller**

```html
       
 public function get_products_in_sub_subcategory(){
$subcategory_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

$this->Account_model->get_products_in_sub_subcategory($subcategory_id);
}
```

Comment: you want to send it with ajax what is the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a value of a variable from view to controller in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675595/how-to-pass-a-value-of-a-variable-from-view-to-controller-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Thanks, The problem is that the variable is not getting passed to the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Put your variable `subcategory_id`  outside the ajax like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  fillgrid();
  function fillgrid()
  {
    var subcategory_id = '<?php echo $sub_id; ?>';
    $("#loader").show();
        $.ajax({
          url:'<?=base_url("Shop/get_products_in_sub_subcategory/");?>'+subcategory_id,
          type:'GET'
        }).done(function (data){
          alert(data);
          console.log(data)
            $("#fillgrid").html(data);
            $("#loader").hide();   
    });
  } 
});
```

And your method `get_products_in_sub_subcategory` should be like this :

```
public function get_products_in_sub_subcategory($subcategory_id)
{
    echo $subcategory_id;
    //$this->Account_model->get_products_in_sub_subcategory($subcategory_id);
    exit; 
}
```

Comment: Why not just `<?=base_url("Shop/get_products_in_sub_subcategory/{$sub_id}");?>'` ? No need to declare a single-use variable.